# Как запретить открывать страницу в новом окне DotNetBrowser?

Tags: javascript, c#

при некоторых кликах - открывается новое окно с дефолтными настройками, а не такими как в родительском окне, так же непонятно как управлять новым окном и настраивать его перед открытием.

пробовал изменять таргет у ссылок из жс после загрузки страницы:

```js
myWindow.Browser.ExecuteJavaScript("
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
     links[i].setAttribute('target', '_self');
         }
");
```

но при клике всё-равно открывается новое окно

Answer (score 0):

оказалось этот код рабочий, но его необходимо запускать каждый раз перед кликом